# Operation with columns in Power BI - Referencing the previous value of the column im creating

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let me present you with a problem

| Date | Value A | Value B | Value C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27/02/2023 | 0% | 1 | 0% |
| 28/02/2023 | 0% | 2 | 0% * 0% ( [Value A] *[Value C] {Index - 1} ) |
| 01/03/2023 | 2% | 1 | 2% |
| 02/03/2023 | 3% | 2 | 3% * 2% |
| 03/03/2023 | 24% | 3 | 24% * (3% * 2%) |
| 06/03/2023 | 90% | 4 | ... |
| 07/03/2023 | 40% | 5 | ... |
| 08/03/2023 | 70% | 6 | ... |
| 09/03/2023 | 62% | 7 | ... |
| 10/03/2023 | 83% | 8 | ... |

This is a representation of a table that i'm working with.
Dates and Value A are given.

Value B i've calculated to return a count of each business days, reseting when the month changes, as you can see below. (Holidays is a list of holidays)

```
Value B = 
var inicial = DATE(YEAR('Table'[Date]),MONTH('Table'[Date]),1)
var inicialdate = MAX(inicial,CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Date]),ALL('Table')))
var finaldate = 'Table'[Date]
return 
NETWORKDAYS(inicialdate ,finaldate ,1,Holidays)
```

I want to add a column, named Value C, that for the first day of the month (or Value B = 1) it will repeat the Value A.

And for the next days untill Value B resets, it will return Value A times the previous value of the calculated Column (Value C).

I'm struggiling to reference previous value of the column i'm creating.

Is this possible ? There is a better way to do it ?

Best Regards!

Comment: Can you add your expected results to your table?

Comment: I've added in the expected result.

Rows that Value B = 1 -> [ Value C is Equal to Value A]                 

Rows that Value B <> 1 -> [Value A * Value C (Previous Row)]